# Google's Open Sans font weight

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I am using Google Open Sans fonts in an html page via:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Only the `font-weight: 600;` makes the font bold. Other values don't seem to make a difference. How to have intermediary font weights for this particular font using the CSS rules? Or must I use some other font?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are using will only consist of `400` font weight font file. Inorder to get other font weight font files, you need to select font weights as well, like

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700');
```

Note that the more font weights you use, the more time it will take to load these files. Inorder to add more font weights, follow the steps below.

1. Go to [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) font page and click on **Select This Font** option
   [image]
2. Maximize the box on the footer, and click on **Customize**

[image]

3. Now here, select the font weights you would like to select for this font. And you are done, go back to **Embed** and get the new URL.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. A heavyweight answer!

Comment: @HankyPanky With more rep comes more responsibilities 

Comment: Might want to spend some time on MS Paint though :D I thought only my arrows were bad